# How to find $\operatorname{Cor}(\Phi(X),\Phi(Y))$

Tags: integration, random-variables, normal-distribution

> Find $Cor(\Phi(X),\Phi(Y)),$ where $X,Y$ are standard normal with $\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y)=\rho$, $ \Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\phi(x)dx$ and $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal density.

Using the substitution $x=\rho y+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}t$, I was able to simplify it a bit and now need to integrate the following
$$E[\Phi(X)\Phi(Y)]=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}\Phi(\rho y+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}t)\Phi(y)\phi(t)\phi(y)\,dt\,dy$$

Any hints how to proceed? I know $\Phi(X)$ follows uniform distribution

PS. The final answer is $\frac 6\pi\arcsin\frac\rho2$

Comment: $(X,Y)$ is supposed to be jointly normal for this result to hold. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954999/finding-correlation-between-cdf-of-two-normal-distributions?noredirect=1&lq=1,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550103/find-the-correlation-coefficient-rho-g-of-gx-hy?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: @StubbornAtom What does it mean to say $X,Y$ are jointly normal?

Comment: It means $(X,Y)$ has a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) ( 2D case). This is not the same as saying $X,Y$ are standard normal with correlation $\rho$. It looks like you have assumed $X,Y$ to be independent in your attempt which is certainly not the case here (unless $\rho=0$).